# how do I link the class with main method in the same file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is my first time using C# to create the program. How do I GetXMLData then add the record after that update the data in xml file? This program do not return me the error, but I could not see the data id "4" has been added into the record.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace LinQ
{
    class Program
    {
        private string path = "TestData.xml";

        private void GetXMLData()
        {
            XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(path);
            var students = from student in testXML.Descendants("Student")
                           select new
                           {
                               ID = Convert.ToInt32(student.Attribute("ID").Value),
                               Name = student.Element("Name").Value
                           };

            foreach (var student in students)
            {
                // Do other operations with each student object
            }
        }
        private void InsertXMLData(string name)
        {
            XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(path);

            XElement newStudent = new XElement("Student",
                                           new XElement("Name", name)
                                       );
            var lastStudent = testXML.Descendants("Student").Last();

            int newID = Convert.ToInt32(lastStudent.Attribute("ID").Value);
            newStudent.SetAttributeValue("ID", 4);
            testXML.Element("Students").Add(newStudent);
            testXML.Save(path);
        }

        private void UpdateXMLData(string name, int id)
        {
            XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(path);
            XElement cStudent = testXML.Descendants("Student").Where(c => c.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals(id.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();

            cStudent.Element("Name").Value = name;
            testXML.Save(path);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //GetXMLData();
            //InsertXMLData(string name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...Because you're not executing any code?

Comment: Call the methods and in Main method and execute the code. Main method is the entry point for your code

Comment: how to call the method in main file?

Comment: Just uncomment then (remove //)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Main function isn't doing anything.

change

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //GetXMLData();
        //InsertXMLData(string name);


    }
```

to

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetXMLData();
        InsertXMLData("paul");
    }
```

you also have to make your methods static.

change

```
private void GetXMLData()

private void InsertXMLData(string name)

private void UpdateXMLData(string name, int id)
```

to

```
private static void GetXMLData()

private static void InsertXMLData(string name)

private static void UpdateXMLData(string name, int id)
```

If you want to access your methods without making them static, you have to create an instance of your object. 
Like:

```
Program myProgram = new Program();
myProgram.GetXMLData();
myProgram.InsertXMLData("paul");
```

Comment: Which, in turn, will result in compile-time errors because the methods aren't static, etc etc etc. There's just too much wrong with this code. =)

Comment: I get the error "Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'LinQ.Program.GetXMLData()' c:\users\visual studio 2012\Projects\LinQ\LinQ\Program.cs 80 13 LinQ
"

Comment: @iop All method should be a static method...like `private static void UpdateXMLData`

Comment: I get the error "Error 1 No overload for method 'InsertXMLData' takes 2 arguments c:\users\visual studio 2012\Projects\LinQ\LinQ\Program.cs 81 13 LinQ
", when I put "InsertXMLData(4, "test4");" in the main file

Comment: my data in TestData.xml file is "<Students>
  <Student ID="1">
    <Name>Test1</Name>    
  </Student>
  <Student ID="2">
    <Name>Test2</Name>    
  </Student>
  <Student ID="3">
    <Name>Test3 </Name>    
  </Student>  
</Students>"

Answer (score 0):

Please give proper path for xml file or keep it in exe location.

Below are the changes required to compile your code

```
class Program
{

    private static string path = "D:\\TestData.xml";


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetXMLData();
        InsertXMLData("XYZ");
    }


    private static void GetXMLData()
    {
        // try
        // {
        XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(path);
        var students = from student in testXML.Descendants("Student")
                       select new
                       {
                           ID = Convert.ToInt32(student.Attribute("ID").Value),
                           Name = student.Element("Name").Value
                       };

        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            // Do other operations with each student object

        }
        //  }
        //catch (Exception err)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        //}
    }
    private static void InsertXMLData(string name)
    {
        //try
        //{
        XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(path);

        XElement newStudent = new XElement("Student",
                                       new XElement("Name", name)
                                   );
        var lastStudent = testXML.Descendants("Student").Last();

        int newID = Convert.ToInt32(lastStudent.Attribute("ID").Value);
        newStudent.SetAttributeValue("ID", 4);
        testXML.Element("Students").Add(newStudent);
        testXML.Save(path);
        //}
        //catch (Exception err)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        //}
    }

    private static void UpdateXMLData(string name, int id)
    {
        //try
        //{
        XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(path);
        XElement cStudent = testXML.Descendants("Student").Where(c => c.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals(id.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();

        cStudent.Element("Name").Value = name;
        testXML.Save(path);
        //}
        //catch (Exception err)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look over the code, it appears there are two problems that could cause the application to perform incorrectly.

Firstly,

The method calls in `Main()` have been commented out, uncomment (remove the leading `//`) for the two methods.

Secondly,

The functions `GetXMLData()`, `InsertXMLData()`, and `UpdateXMLData()` are not static, and require a class instance to be used.  You can fix this by adding the keyword `static` or use a class instance to call the functions.

Either change the function definitions to something like

```
 private static void GetXMLData()
 private static void InsertXMLData()
 private static void UpdateXMLData()
```

or use a class instance

```
 Program p = new Program();
 p.GetXMLData();
```

There are no doubt other issues within the code, but this should get you started.